# jQuery plugin in theory

Tags: jquery

I'm planning to build small plugin in jQuery - just want to check your opinion whether jQuery is the tool for the job.

Basically, I would have two textareas, where I would enter strings (comma or new line separated).

e.g:
 
textarea 1 content: `1,2,3,4`
textarea 2 content: `a,b,c,d`

After pressing submit I would like jQuery to create `every possible combination ( 1a,1b,1c,1d,2a,2b etc....)` and return that in a->z order.

**Q1. Can jQuery detect new line?(without html mark-up)**

**Q2. Every list will have 100 - 1000 entries. Will jQuery cope with it?**

**Q3. Do you know any jQuery function which do something like `every possible combination` or would that be for loop?**

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: jQuery cannot help you in any of these tasks, but you can stick to plain JavaScript.

Comment: (1) Yes, (2) Yes, (3) Yea, I guess, although it's trivial to implement

Comment: A function will suit the case better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple implementation:

```
function getValues( id1, id2, delimiter ) {    
    var elem1, elem2,
        arr1, arr2,
        i, j, 
        result = [];

    elem1 = document.getElementById( id1 );
    elem2 = document.getElementById( id2 );
    arr1 = elem1.value.split( delimiter );
    arr2 = elem2.value.split( delimiter );

    for ( i = 0; i < arr1.length; i += 1 ) {
        for ( j = 0; j < arr2.length; j += 1 ) {
            result.push( arr1[i].trim() + arr2[j].trim() );
        }
    }

    return result.sort().toString();
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/YvgAM/5/

Explanation:

This function accepts three parameters:

- the first two parameters are ID names of the two TEXTAREA elements,
- the third parameter is the delimiter (string), eg. `','`, `'\n'`.

First, you get the elements, then you grab their contents (the text) and split that into an array using the supplied delimiter.

Now, you just use two nested for loop to construct an array of values.

Last, you sort that array and cast it into String.

Comment: Great job! Can you spear a minute a go through the code, please? Sometimes I still struggle to understand fully the way the code is working.

Comment: Nice!  One recommendation: instead of passing in IDs, pass in the elements themselves.  That way it works even if the elements don't have IDs.

Comment: @Šime Vidas - very simple and straight forward! Thanks for your help! Last question, where in the code you are setting to return value as comma separated, I can't work that one out.

Comment: @NewUser The `toString` method of arrays does that by default. If you want to print the result with a different delimiter, use `join()`. For instance: `return result.sort().join( ' - ' );`

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a good job for jQuery; in general, jquery plugins are useful when you want something highly reusable that you can instantiate with $("some-selector").make_my_custom_thing();

1. jQuery doesn't provide any native way to detect newlines, you'll need to split the strings yourself over whichever character you like (either commas, new lines, white space, etc).
2. I'd be less concerned here with jQuery couping with your objects and more with how your code handles it. jQuery provides iterators over collections, but you write the function that it calls on each element. Make sure the function you pass to jQuery.each is fast enough for your purposes.
3. If you're not concerned with uniqueness, you can just use a nested loop. Eg:

(psuedo-code)

```
combinations = [];
for (var i in collection_1) {
  for (var j in collection_2) {
    combinations.append(i + j); //assumes string addition
  }
}
```